# pyautoguiで取得した時点と、同一画像を保存後に再読み込み時のHSV値で差が出てしまう

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, 画像, pyautogui

タイトルの件、原因がわからず行き詰ってしまいましたのでご質問させて頂きました。

#### 質問事項

Pythonで、以下2つのHSV値を比較するプログラムを書いています。

- pyautogui.screenshotで取得した画像に対して、np.arrayに変換 → cv2.cvtColor でHSVに変換して値を取得
- 上記をRGBで保存したファイルに対して、np.fromfileで読込 → cv2.imdecode → cv2.cvtColor でHSVに変換して値を取得

両方とも元は同一画像のため、HSV値も同一値を想定したのですが、結果として差異が出てしまっています。
読込、変換の仕方なのか、仕様として差異がでるものなのか、について、ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたいと考えています。

#### 環境

Python 3.8.8
cv2.**version** '4.5.3'
np.**version** '1.20.1'
pyautogui.**version** '0.9.53'

#### ソース

hsvList1 と hsvList2 で差異が出てしまう

```
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np

#取得座標の設定
x = 1000
y = 1000
width = 1000
hight = 1000

#スクリーンショットを取得
sc = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, width, hight))

#np.arrayに変換
sc_im = np.array(sc, dtype = 'uint8')

#BGRからHSVに変換
sc_im = cv2.cvtColor(sc_im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#HSVの最大値と最小値を取得
h_min_1 = sc_im.T[0].flatten().min()
h_max_1 = sc_im.T[0].flatten().max()

s_min_1 = sc_im.T[1].flatten().min()
s_max_1 = sc_im.T[1].flatten().max()

v_min_1 = sc_im.T[2].flatten().min()
v_max_1 = sc_im.T[2].flatten().max()

hsvList1 = [h_min_1, h_max_1, s_min_1, s_max_1, v_min_1, v_max_1]
print(str(hsvList1))

#RGBに変換して保存する
sc = sc.convert('RGB')
sc.save("test.jpg")

#保存したファイルを読込み
n = np.fromfile("test.jpg", np.uint8)
file_im = cv2.imdecode(n, flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

#HSVに変換
file_im = cv2.cvtColor(file_im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#HSVの最大値と最小値を取得
h_min_2 = file_im.T[0].flatten().min()
h_max_2 = file_im.T[0].flatten().max()

s_min_2 = file_im.T[1].flatten().min()
s_max_2 = file_im.T[1].flatten().max()

v_min_2 = file_im.T[2].flatten().min()
v_max_2 = file_im.T[2].flatten().max()

hsvList2 = [h_min_2, h_max_2, s_min_2, s_max_2, v_min_2, v_max_2]
print(str(hsvList2))
```

#### printの出力例

```
[0, 176, 0, 255, 2, 255]
[0, 179, 0, 255, 0, 255]
```

Comment: なぜ JPEG 形式(非可逆圧縮)で保存しているのでしょう？ また、`sc.convert('RGB')` で `RGB` に変換して保存していますが、`cv2.cvtColor(file_im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` で `BGR` から `HSV` へ変換していますね。

Comment: 早速のコメントありがとうございます。
ご回答の「JPEG 形式(非可逆圧縮)」の箇所が本件の原因かと思いました…

確認したい部分のみ抜粋したソースになっていたので十分説明がしきれておりませんでしたが、過去保存した画像をもとに、今回取得した画像とHSV値で比較する、ということを目的にしておりました。

冒頭部分が全てかと存じますが、上記を踏まえて以下回答となります。
・なぜ JPEG 形式(非可逆圧縮)で保存しているのでしょう？ 
→ 過去の分は一度画像として残して、それを次回取得時の比較対象とするためです。

・cv2.cvtColor(file_im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) で BGR から HSV へ変換していますね。
→ 失礼しました。本箇所は正しくは「RGB から HSV」となります。（結果の差異ありは変わらず）

Comment: 手元の環境で `PNG` で保存、`cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV` で変換すると一致します。

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます。
私の環境でもPNGの場合、一致することを確認しました。

非常に悩んでいたので大変助かりました！
お二人ともご対応ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

ご回答頂き解決しました。原因および対応は以下となります。
◆原因
JPEG 形式(非可逆圧縮)で保存した画像を読み込んでいたため、スクリーンショット取得時と差異が出ていた。（仕様通り）

◆対策
　画像をPNG形式で保存し、読込を行う。（差異がないことは確認済み）

◆補足
　ソースコード上、画像読込後、「cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV」となっていましたが、「cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV」が正しいです。